# Powershell ps2exe config variable

Tags: powershell, ps2exe-gui

I would like To store a variable in a config file for a .ps1(powershell script) converted to .exe using ps2exe

```
$LnkPath="...\" #Directory Path of .lnk
$LnkFile="\nnnn.lnk" #name of .lnk file
Invoke-Item $ScriptPath + $LnkFile
```

I was hoping to have `$LnkFile` and `$LnkPath` as config file variables so if the version of the lnk stops working, i can just point to a new lnk.

There is a reason why the version of the .lnk file stops working, but it is complicated, and not worth anyone's time.

edit:
[image: Ps2exe-gui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config file created with the optional `-configFile` switch isn't meant for use by the wrapped script - it merely contains runtime metadata for the generated executable (in the form of an XML file placed alongside the executable with additional extension `.config`).

However, you can create your own config file.

While PowerShell has a configuration-data format that uses hashtable-literal syntax, which can be *read* with [`Import-PowerShellDataFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-powershelldatafile), as of PowerShell 7.2.x there is no way to create this format *programmatically*.

A simple alternative that supports both reading and programmatic creation is to use a JSON file:

The following assumes that your script file is `foo.ps1`, to be converted to `foo.exe`, with a configuration file `foo.json` located in the same directory (which you'll have to bundle with your `.exe` file when deploying it):

First, create your JSON config file:

```bash
@{ LnkPath = '...\'; LnkFile = 'nnnn.lnk' } | ConvertTo-Json > foo.json
```

Now you can read this file from `foo.ps1` / `foo.exe` as follows:

```bash
# Determine this script's / executable's full path.
$scriptOrExePath = 
  if ($PSCommandPath) { # Running as .ps1
    $PSCommandPath
  } else { # Running as .exe"
    Convert-Path ([Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[0])
  }

# Look for the JSON config file in the same directory as this script / executable, load it and parse it into an object.
$config = 
  Get-Content -Raw ([IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($scriptOrExePath, '.json')) |
  ConvertFrom-Json

# $config is now an object with .LnkPath and .LnkFile properties.
$config # Output for diagnostic purposes.
```

Note the need to use `[Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()` to determine the executable path when running as an `.exe` file, because the usual automatic variables indicating the script path (`$PSCommandPath`) and script directory (`$PSScriptRoot`) aren't available then.